# Mysqli result while loop returns null

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, while-loop

This code used to work last time i checked then i made some changes (but didn't change the core actions) and now it doesn't and i can't understand why, is there something i'm missing?

```
require("./dbAccess.php");
mysqli_set_charset($dbConnection, 'utf8mb4');

if($query = mysqli_query($dbConnection, 
"SELECT * FROM table")){
mysqli_close($dbConnection);

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query));
    {
      var_dump($row);
    }
}
else {echo (mysqli_error($dbConnection)); mysqli_close($dbConnection);}
```

The table has 2 rows, mysqli_num_rows confirms it and if i var_dump without the loop i correctly get the first row but as soon as it goes through the loop the var_dump results null.

Thanks

Comment: Uhm… when the query is successful, you explicitly close the connection…!?

Comment: mysqli_fetch_assoc doesn't require a db connection to work, why should i keep it open?

Comment: Why would you think that‽ It *fetches* the data from the database. It doesn’t explicitly require a connection parameter, since that’s included in the result set parameter that it takes. The underlying connection to the database must still be active.

Comment: I thought all the data it needed was already stored in the query result (why would it work outside the while loop then?). Anyways, i tried closing the connection at the end but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the damn semicolon, i spent too much time trying to understand what went wrong since everything worked before and it didn't output any error.

bad

```
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query));
    {
      var_dump($row);
    }
```

good

```
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
      var_dump($row);
    }
```